# Get pre-defined records in sql result irrespective of its existence

Tags: sql

I have a table where there are duplicate values in the employee name but the description is unique. I want to select only 5 employees for which I have names predefined in the script.

```
select
Employee in (John A, Ronny C, Harry D, David R, Alison R)
from Employee table 
where employee in (John A, Ronny C, Harry D, David R, Alison R) and description like "% Manager %"
```

In the above script if Johan A is not the manager then his record will not appear, I want his name in the result but should have "NULL" in the description column

Comment: Show us some sample table data - and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use `case..when` as follows:

```
select name, case when description not like '%Manager%' then description end as description
  from Employee  
 where name in ('John A', 'Ronny C', 'Harry D', 'David R', 'Alison R')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when description like '%Manager%' then description end) as manager_description
from employee
where name in ('John A', 'Ronny C', 'Harry D', 'David R', 'Alison R')
group by name;
```

This returns all matching names in the table.  If there is a "manager" description, then that is returned.  If not, then `NULL`.